# sql group by not working on ignited datatables

Tags: sql, codeigniter, datatables

So I have this simple query that if I run it on sql server management studio it gives me results.

```
Select name, count(*) As thecount from Restaurants group by name
```

I am using codeigniter and a wrapper library for datatables called [ignited datatable](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php) . I am using it because its easier to integrate sql results to a nice json format for tables. The problem I ran into is that the group by function used by this library gives me an error.. This is my query

```
$this->datatables->select("name, count(*) as thecount");
$this->datatables->from("Restaurants");
$this->datatables->group_by('name');
echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

I believe this is a straightforward query it shouldn't give me any errors but when it echoes it gives me a database error

```
Error Number: 42000

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Column 'Restaurants.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
SELECT * FROM Restaurants GROUP BY name
```

There is something wrong with the group_by functionality in this library because if I do another query without the group by it works just fine.
This is the group_by functionality in the datatables library

```
 public function group_by($val)
    {
      $this->group_by[] = $val;
      $this->ci->db->group_by($val);
      return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to print out the query you build?  It looks like it is selecting the `id` column.

Comment: I updated my error response with the query it generates, I feel like its ignoring the whole select statement

Comment: I updated my answer.  Can you try again?

Comment: In the error message query is "select * from " but in the actual query you have only selected name and count. The 'get_total_results' function in datatable library might be causing this issue.